# How to change TTStyledTextLabel link font

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, three20

I tried setting the font property on TTStyledText as well definition a TTStyleWithFont but both do not work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261641/ttstyledtextlabel-offset-between-link-and-regular-text-when-changing-from-default will help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the font is being reset in TTStyledTextLabel. Three20 gives precedence to the font property on TTStyledTextLabel over TTStyledText